# EventListener's e.preventDefault(); not working for inner-page href="#hash" links

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am currently building a WordPress site and trying to prevent inner page links for firing. The part of code I use is:

```
   var numberLinks = Array.from( document.querySelectorAll('.benefits-links .inner-nav-link > .number-link '));

    numberLinks.forEach( function (link) {
        link.addEventListener('click' , numberClick)
    })

    function numberClick(e) {       
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log(e);
    }
```

When a `<a></a>` tag is clicked the event is logged but the window still jumps to the `href` anchor.

Am I missing something? How to stop the execution of the link and add my own functions?
Page of reference is https://dev.cognitivplus.com/grey-box/

Thank you

Comment: Have you placed that JS code so it runs *after* the element exists in the DOM?

Comment: Not sure, I think so... the element is present but with `height:0` and gets height:`auto` later. Also, I presume it's present since the console logs the event. I used the console.log to test the execution of the numberClick() function

Answer (score 0):

Just to make a contribution, what made the trick was to add:

```
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
```

apparently, some relative element was triggering the link

Answer (score -2):

Try bellow codes, it will work :

```
numberLinks.forEach( function (link) {

    link.addEventListener('mouseenter',function(e){
        var myLink = e.currentTarget;
        myLink.khref = myLink.href;
        myLink.href = "#";
    });
    link.addEventListener('mouseout',function(e){
        var myLink = e.currentTarget;
        myLink.href = myLink.khref        
    });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem in the question, and introduces accessibility problems for non-mouse users.

Comment: Ohh you didn't mentioned that for non-mouse user, there have another solution too, But I already down voted  ! ahh !

Comment: Does your other solution _also_ not solve the problem in the question?

Answer (score -2):

Hi I do it this way,

I use a specific class for all the elements i dont want to trigger.

```js
var numberLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.benefits-links');
console.log(numberLinks);
numberLinks.forEach( function (link) {
    link.addEventListener('click' , (e)=>{ 
    e.preventDefault();
 console.log("anything will trigger except pokemon");
    return false 
    })
})
```

```css
.benefits-links{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<a href="www.google.com" class="benefits-links">Google</a>
<br>
<a href="www.pokemonshowdown.com">Pokemon</a>
<br>
<a href="www.stackoverflow.com" class="benefits-links">Stack Overflow</a>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: hey stan, I added a class-specific selector but still, the `.number-link`  directs to the href section

Comment: @GiannisDallas log the variable where you stored the <a> alements and make sure you are getting the html elements here is the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/368kgwuc/45/